# Defining variable by logical subseting on time interval in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
    id event state      time
 1:  A     0  NULL 0.8998250
 2:  A     1  NULL 1.1459127
 3:  A     0  NULL 1.1879722
 4:  A     2  NULL 1.5158930
 5:  A     0  NULL 2.4703966
 6:  B     0  NULL 0.8895393
 7:  B     1  NULL 1.5823427
 8:  B     2  NULL 2.2228495
 9:  B     0  NULL 3.2171193
10:  B     0  NULL 3.8728251
11:  C     1  NULL 0.7085305
12:  C     0  NULL 1.2525965
13:  C     2  NULL 1.8467385
14:  C     0  NULL 2.1358983
15:  C     0  NULL 2.2830119
```

I want to give the variable `state` the value 1 for the rows between event 1 and event 2. The two events occure only once for each `id` and `event=1` allways comes before `event=2`.

The following code genarates the above data.table,

```
library(data.table)

# Defining variabels and data.table
id <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=5)
set.seed(123)
event <- c(sample(c(0,1),2,F),sample(c(0,0,2),3,F),
           sample(c(0,1),2,F),sample(c(0,0,2),3,F),
           sample(c(0,1),2,F),sample(c(0,0,2),3,F))
state <- "NULL"
time <- c(apply(matrix(runif(3*5),5,3),2,cumsum))
DT <- data.table(id,event,state,time) 
DT
```

and I have tried the code below to assign the value 1 to the state variable between the two time points of `event==1` and `event==2`.

```
DT[time>=time[event==1] & time<=time[event==2],state:="1",by=id]
```

But this generates the following output:

```
    id event state      time
 1:  A     0  NULL 0.8998250
 2:  A     1  NULL 1.1459127
 3:  A     0     1 1.1879722
 4:  A     2     1 1.5158930
 5:  A     0  NULL 2.4703966
 6:  B     0     1 0.8895393
 7:  B     1  NULL 1.5823427
 8:  B     2     1 2.2228495
 9:  B     0  NULL 3.2171193
10:  B     0  NULL 3.8728251
11:  C     1  NULL 0.7085305
12:  C     0     1 1.2525965
13:  C     2  NULL 1.8467385
14:  C     0     1 2.1358983
15:  C     0  NULL 2.2830119
```

Where the `state=1`'s are clearly placed in the wrong places in the data.table. I can't figure out what data.table is doing. Can you see why data.table is behaving in this way and is there a nifty solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, try this:

```
DT[,state:= ifelse(time>=time[event==1] & time<=time[event==2],1,state),by=id]

#    id event state      time
# 1:  A     0  NULL 0.8998250
# 2:  A     1     1 1.1459127
# 3:  A     0     1 1.1879722
# 4:  A     2     1 1.5158930
# 5:  A     0  NULL 2.4703966
# 6:  B     0  NULL 0.8895393
# 7:  B     1     1 1.5823427
# 8:  B     2     1 2.2228495
# 9:  B     0  NULL 3.2171193
#10:  B     0  NULL 3.8728251
#11:  C     1     1 0.7085305
#12:  C     0     1 1.2525965
#13:  C     2     1 1.8467385
#14:  C     0  NULL 2.1358983
#15:  C     0  NULL 2.2830119
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Comment: You filtered first lines where `time[event==1] & time<=time[event==2]` and THEN grouped by `id`. You can see this by doing `dt[time>=time[event==1] & time<=time[event==2],]`

Answer (score 2):

Without using `ifelse`, we can extract the row index using `.I` and then assign those rows of `state` to '1'.

```
DT[DT[,.I[time>=time[event==1] & time<=time[event==2]], 
                                 by=id]$V1, state:='1'][]
#    id event state      time
# 1:  A     0  NULL 0.8998250
# 2:  A     1     1 1.1459127
# 3:  A     0     1 1.1879722
# 4:  A     2     1 1.5158930
# 5:  A     0  NULL 2.4703966
# 6:  B     0  NULL 0.8895393
# 7:  B     1     1 1.5823427
# 8:  B     2     1 2.2228495
# 9:  B     0  NULL 3.2171193
#10:  B     0  NULL 3.8728251
#11:  C     1     1 0.7085305
#12:  C     0     1 1.2525965
#13:  C     2     1 1.8467385
#14:  C     0  NULL 2.1358983
#15:  C     0  NULL 2.2830119
```